# Discord Bot assings roles based off user request

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm kinda new to building my own Bot, so far at a point were I want my users to able to use the command **!Sub "Their ID"** and my bot will pull the info from my web API and assign them to their role
example.
ID 1 = Premium 
ID 2 = Super Premium

So far I've got this:

```js
const request = require('request');

request('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  console.log(body.url);
  console.log(body.explanation);
});
```

Now if I want to assign the roles, how would it look like...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I understand you want to happen based on the question:

> User: "!Sub 1"
>   Bot: * assigns user to role 1 *

If that's what you want to do, here's how I would proceed:

- You need to store your role IDs so that you can assign them later. You can also use the role name, but you'll need to remember that you can't change it without updating the code.
- You then need to use [`GuildMember.roles.add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) to add the role to the user.

Here's an example:

```js
// I'll assume that you already have the command structure set up, so these variables will be set:
// - message: The message with the command (its content will be '!Sub 1' in this case)

let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == 'Premium') // You can use you role's name here
let roleID = '1234...' // This would be your role ID

message.member.roles.add(role || roleID)
```

That would be the way to add the role. You'll just need to switch the role name/ID depending on what the user entered, which will be your first argument.